# Issue with invetory_items.json on Shopify app development

Tags: symfony, shopify, liquid, inventory, items

I'm working on a private app to manage the database and the inventory of a Shopify Online Store in Symfony and I'm looking for getting all products or inventory of the store.

I tried with the url https://{{api_key}}:{{password}}@{{shopify_domain}}/admin/products.json , but it gets only 50 products of 180 000.

So I tried with the url
https://{{apiKey}}:{{password}}@{{shopifyDomain}}/admin/api/{{apiVersion}}/inventory_items.json , and it returns ids : missing parameter or invalid.

I don't know how to manage this exception, I tried to insert id of a product but it didn't work.

Extra info, I have built the url with Twig.

If somebody know how to help me, I'm open to suggestions !

Thanks,

Karim HADJ-ABDELKADER

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices. With the RestAPI, the header response from Shopify contains a link to the next page of products. So you would setup a loop. Ask for your products and follow the link to the next page. Hence, you have to page through the products. Second, you can use GraphQL API and issue a bulk download command for all inventory, specific to inventory items. You receive a link you can use to download the entire inventory as a JSONL file. That is probably your best bet to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that the inventory changes every day, so if I upload a JSONL file to the application, the inventory won't be the current version. Another thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using the shopify-php-sdk Github repository which is supposed to be connected to the Shopify API via a config file.

Comment: Why is it a problem. On a daily basis, you download your current inventory and update Shopify as necessary. It makes zero difference what language or scripting you choose to use, they are all the same in the end. It is what you do, not how you choose to do it.

Comment: It's a problem because the inventory contains more than 200 000 products, which have each several variants, so it's a heavy workload for a small company with just 2 employees. So is there a possibility to display all the inventory in real-time via the Shopify API ?

Comment: You download 200,000 products with one GQL call. You get a single file to work with. Has nothing to do with 1, 2 or 200 employees. It is data processing. With that file, you can now update Shopify, using a script. Did you know you can update 100 SKUs (variants) with one API call? So ya. 200,000 divided by 100 leaves you with what 2000 API calls? With rest that is one every 2 seconds or 1000 seconds. Last I checked that was ~ 16 minutes. Not sure why you think this is an employee issue? It amounts to a little computing a not that much time.